# Show image on button click and hide when iframe loads

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show the img.png once the upload button is clicked. Here is the code of that button:

```
<button style="padding: 4px;margin-top: 30px;border-radius: 0px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></button>
<div id="image_details"></div>
```

I want to hide it when the values of file names come inside the `IFRAME`. The file uploading code is below.

```
<form target="upload_target" id="fileupload" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('upload_file/upload_it'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="fileUpload btn btn-warning">
   <span>Browse</span>
        <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" class="upload" />
</div>
<input id="uploadFile" style="width: 160px; margin-top: 30px;float: left;height: 34px;" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
<button style="padding: 4px;margin-top: 30px;border-radius: 0px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></button>
<div id="image_details"></div>
</form>
</div>
    </div>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-left:0px;">
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="border:0px; background-color:#FFFFFF; " scrolling="no">  
            </iframe>                   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery, you should add two events:

```
$("#fileupload").on("submit", function()
  {
     //Put here the code to SHOW image
  });
```

and

```
$("#upload_target").on("load", function()
  {
     //Put here the code to HIDE image
  });
```

Comment: With little bit change It works i just put the on load event inside the button click. Thanks for sharing your idea.